# Using BehaviorSubject to share data between sibling components

Tags: angular

I am still learning Angular and trying to see how `BehaviorSubject` works but got stuck where to start. Here is waht I am trying to do:

Create a search box component called `HeroDetailComponent` where I enter some text and based on this text I will search a list of heroes and show them to user using another component `HeroesComponent`. Now this communication should be done using a service component with help of `BehaviorSubject`.

Here is my main component:

**app.component.html**

```
<app-hero-detail></app-hero-detail>
<app-heroes></app-heroes>
```

Here is my **hero-detail.component.html** this i am using it as search box:

```
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [(ngModel)]="hero.name" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
```

and the corresponding **hero-detail.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: './hero-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-detail.component.css']
})
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This is my **heroes.component.html**, here I am displaying the search results:

```
<h2>My Heroes</h2>

<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

and its **heroes.component.ts** :

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from '../hero';
import { HEROES } from '../mock-heroes';
import { HeroService } from '../hero.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-heroes',
  templateUrl: './heroes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./heroes.component.css']
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  heroes = HEROES;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }
    
    getHeroes(): void {
      // Logic to access heroes list matching search text and display to user
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

Here is my service component:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HeroService {

    private searchSource = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
    searchText = this.searchSource.asObservable();

    constructor() { }

    searchByName(name: string) {
        this.searchSource.next(name);
    }

}
```

This is my mock data of heroes list:

```
import { Hero } from './hero';

export const HEROES: Hero[] = [
  { id: 11, name: 'Mr. Nice' },
  { id: 12, name: 'Narco' },
  { id: 13, name: 'Bombasto' },
  { id: 14, name: 'Celeritas' },
  { id: 15, name: 'Magneta' },
  { id: 16, name: 'RubberMan' },
  { id: 17, name: 'Dynama' },
  { id: 18, name: 'Dr IQ' },
  { id: 19, name: 'Magma' },
  { id: 20, name: 'Tornado' }
];
```

Can you please help me how to have this should be implemented?

**Updated:**

I followed steps given in trichetriche answer, but I am getting below errors:

```
ERROR in src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts(17,16): error TS2339: Property 'formValue$' does not exist on type 'HeroService'.
src/app/hero-detail/hero-detail.component.ts(17,61): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'startWith'.
src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts(17,13): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'combineLatest'.
src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts(19,22): error TS2339: Property 'formValue$' does not exist on type 'HeroService'.
src/app/heroes/heroes.component.ts(21,5): error TS2552: Cannot find name 'map'. Did you mean 'Map'?
```

How to solve these errors?

**Update:**
The above errors are solved now. Now I started facing issue with observable:

```
Observable.js:54 TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.
    at subscribeTo (subscribeTo.js:41)
    at subscribeToResult (subscribeToResult.js:11)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestSubscriber._complete (combineLatest.js:62)
    at CombineLatestSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.complete (Subscriber.js:66)
    at Observable._subscribe (subscribeToArray.js:8)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable._trySubscribe (Observable.js:43)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:29)
    at CombineLatestOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/observable/combineLatest.js.CombineLatestOperator.call (combineLatest.js:32)
    at Observable.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Observable.js.Observable.subscribe (Observable.js:24)
    at MapOperator.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapOperator.call (map.js:18)
```

Can you please help me in solving this.

Comment: please make a demo on stackblitz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subjects and BehaviorSubjects are proxies : they act both as observables, and observers.

You can make the observers of the proxies react when you cann `subject.next(value)` : the difference between a subject, and a behavior subject, is that the observer of a subject will receive the current value of the proxy (while a subject will only get the value of the next `next`).

So, basically,

```
BehaviorSubject === Subject.pipe(startWith(someValue))
```

Now, you don't really need a behavior subject to do what you want. You have a cleaner way of doing so, use reactive forms and its `valueChanges` property.

In your form, use this :

```html
  <div>
    <label>name:
      <input [formControl]="heroName" placeholder="name"/>
    </label>
  </div>
```

```js
export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  heroName = new FormControl('');
  constructor(
    private service: HeroService
  ) {
    this.service.formValue$ = this.heroName.valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''));
  }
}
```

You will create a form control, then inject your service into your component, and finally, you will use the `valueChanges` observable of the form control to sort your heroes in the sibling.

In the service, simply add a `formValue$: Observable<string>` to declare the variable. (`xx$` is just a naming convention for observables, to spot them quick).

You need the `startWith` operator to trigger a first value change on your control (otherwise, the value don't change unless you type something)

Finally, in the sibling :

```js
export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {

  private _heroesList$ = new BehaviorSubject(HEROES);

  heroes$;

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) { }

    getHeroes(): void {
      this.heroes$ = combineLatest(
        this._heroesList$,
        this.heroService.formValue$
      ).pipe(
        map(([list, name]) => list.filter(hero => hero.name.includes(name)))
      );
    }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

```html
<h2>My Heroes</h2>

<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes$ | async"
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

By donig so, you create a new stream, that is made of both the form value and the list, and you map the result to return a filtered list of your heroes. You use the `async` pipe to let angular deal with the subscriptions, which is a good practice and prevents you from forgetting to unsubscribe.

Comment: `BehaviorSubject === Subject.pipe(startWith(someValue))` not entirely true

Comment: @Jota.Toledo hence the "basically" :)

Comment: Thanks trichetriche, I am getting errors when I am trying to use this answer, I updated my post with details, can you please check it once

Comment: @learner 1) & 5) you forgot to add `formValue$: Observable<string>` in your service 2) & 4) import `import { startWith, map } from 'rxjs/operators` 3) `import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs`

Comment: @trichetriche, Thanks the errors are gone. Now when the page is loaded I am seeing errors in browser console, when I enter text in search box, nothing is happened. I added the error details in my updated post. Can you please check.

Comment: You forgot to set some variable of the `combineLatest`, are all of your variables correctly instanciated ?

Comment: @trichetriche,  followed all the steps given in this answer, is there anything I need to add to service component?

Comment: @learner oh yes, that's my bad ! you will have to move the content of `HeroDetailComponent#ngOnInit` into the constructor, and the `combineLatest` code into the `getHeroes()` function.

Answer (score -1):

```
getHeroes(): void {

  this.heroService.searchText
   .pipe(
     map((name) => HEROES.filter((hero) => hero.name.indexOf(name) !== -1))
   )
   .subscribe((results) => this.heroes = results);
}
```

Then just loop it like:

```
<ul class="heroes">
  <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
    <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I am not using http or authentication